# Jquery and CSS Button toggle rotation animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a problem with my button. I want it to be toggle like. 1st click - rotate to predefined value. 2nd click - go to original value. Both need to be keyframed so the animation looks smooth and not just instant.

HTML

```
<center><a id="c_button" class="c_button"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></a><center>
```

CSS

```
.c_button{
background-color:#607D8B;
border-radius:50px;
padding: 15px;
display:inline-block;
color:#F5F5F5;
font-family:Roboto;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:bold;
width:24px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 0px;
}.c_button:hover {
background-color:#56707D;
position:relative;
}.c_button:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}

/*used to create rotation animation*/
a.on {
-webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
-o-transform: rotate(135deg);
transform: rotate(135deg);

-webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
-moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
-o-transition: 200ms linear all;
transition: 200ms linear all;
background-color:#56707D;
}
a.on:hover {
background-color:#607D8B;
}
a.on:active{
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a#c_button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("on");
});
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/csck5j3h/
I have the first toggle animation figured out. Can't seem to figure out the other one.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/csck5j3h/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
-webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
-moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
-o-transition: 200ms linear all;
transition: 200ms linear all;
```

Needs to be added to `a`, not `a.on`

```js
$('#c_button').click(function(){
     $(this).find('a').toggleClass('on'); 
});
```

```css
.c_button {
    background-color:#607D8B;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#F5F5F5;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.c_button:hover {
    background-color:#56707D;
    position:relative;
}
.c_button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
/*used to create rotation animation for JS*/
a{
  -webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
    -moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
    -o-transition: 200ms linear all;
    transition: 200ms linear all;  
}
 a.on {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    
    background-color:#56707D;
}
a.on:hover {
    background-color:#607D8B;
}
a.on:active {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c_button">
    <center><a id="c_button" class="c_button">A</a><center>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I wonder can another animation be set after the first one? So instead of playing the animation backwards. Playing another animation after the current.

Comment: If this is what you're looking for, why accept another answer that was later than mine? @meganukebmp

Comment: @meganukebmp And yes, that is possible. Want me to show you?

Comment: Yours was not exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion. The method was right. But I liked his method more (looks more clean code wise). I'm a beginner in all of this and like my code a little more understandable and clean so I can use it later without getting confused on what a class does or how a JS works. Anyways yes I would like to see how to add a second animation.

Comment: @meganukebmp You could just check if the element has the class `on` when clicking on it and then add let's say another class or something to play that other effect.

Comment: Yes I got it figured out. Thanks. Also after your post edit it's right. looks better.

Comment: I'm just glad I can help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add transition time your `c_button` css class like below

```
.c_button {
    background-color:#607D8B;
    border-radius:50px;
    padding: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#F5F5F5;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0px;
    /*add transition time effect here*/
    -webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
    -moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
    -o-transition: 200ms linear all;
     transition: 200ms linear all;
}
```

and use your jQuery as it is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#c_button').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/csck5j3h/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
a{
   -webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
   -moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
   -o-transition: 200ms linear all;
   transition: 200ms linear all;
}
```

it allow you to have the transition whenever it isn't on